# RA4 Pin pin on PIC16F876 problems

Tags: pic, digital-logic, embedded

I am using the PIC16F876 to program an AD9833. I am using the RA2 pin for FSYNC, RA3 pin for SCLK and RA4 pin for SDATA. I have used ADCON1 = 0x07 to set all the A ports as digital and PORTA = 0x00 to set all the ports as outputs.

The problem is that the RA4 pin is not responding to commands. I know this is a special pin but I think it can be used as a digital I/O.

Can someone tell me what I am missing? I assume there is another register write which enables RA4 as a standard digital I/O but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I have found out that I cannot drive this pin high, it needs an external pull up resistor. But if anyone can shed more light on this is would still appreciate it.

Comment: Can you confirm that the microcontroller is on, can you toggle an LED with any pin?

Comment: It clearly states in the documentation that RA4 is an open drain type - RTFM (page 7)

Comment: Yes this PIC works fine. All other Pins work OK. I was not familiar with the open drain type pins. Do I just connect it to 5v through a resistor? (leaving the connection to the SDATA pin on the AD9833 as it is?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RA4 pin is **open drain (when you write 0 it's connected to the ground, when you write 1 it's floating)** so you need a pull-up resistor.
You don't have to change your circuit, simply add a resistor between RA4 and Vcc (in your case 5 V). You can use a standard 10 kΩ resistor (that is usually great), lower values like 4.7 kΩ can be used if it's necessary more speed.

Comment: Nooo.. It's been driving me crackers for a week now! Thank you, Guru.